# method is undefined for the type. JSF Primefaces

Tags: java

i have a problem with my jsf application. I have the declaration below:

```
private static ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote service;

private List<Agentinfo> agentsActive;
..........
..........
agentsActive = service.getAgentsActiveOrSuspended();
```

And in `ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote` (which is an interface) I have

```
public abstract List<Agentinfo> getAgentsActiveOrSuspended();
```

And in `ServiceFilteredAgents` (class that implements `ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote`) I have

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jpa")
private EntityManager em;
.............
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Agentinfo> getAgentsActiveOrSuspended() {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT a FROM Agentinfo a)").getResultList();
}
```

I still don't understand why it say that the method `getAgentsActiveOrSuspended()` is undefined for the type `ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote`.

Thanks you in advance and tell me if you want I post all the code in my class

Comment: The abstract keyword does not belong in an interface. And this question has nothing to do with JSF or Primefaces so those tags are incorrect.

Comment: I see you removed the unnecessary tags, what about that invalid abstract keyword you're using in your interface? What happens when you remove it? Does the error change or even better go away?

Comment: Gimby i tried but it doesn't changes anything still have the problem

Comment: I guess this is a compile error? Which piece of code you posted is exactly not compiling? You're also positive that you don't accidentally have two interfaces names ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote in two different packages?

Comment: i found the solution finally. Thank you everybody

Comment: that's good but then post the solution as an answer so others may possibly be helped too!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution the class ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote was not in the same project as my class where i called 
    
        `agentsActive = service.getAgentsActiveOrSuspended();`

so i just add the jar file of the project where i have class ServiceFilteredAgentsRemote to the other project